# How to get the MAX column using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize and I have been having problems to get the MAX of a column

```
var userId = req.body.userId;
Sensor.findAll(
{
    where : {
        userId : userId
    }, 
    attributes: [
        sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.literal('temperature'))
    ],
    include: [{
        model: models.Temperature
    }]
}).then(function(sensor_result) {
    res.status(200).json({ status:"success", data: sensor_result });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(409).json({ status:"error", data: null, message:"Something went wrong, please try again." });
})
```

This works but if I change the temperature column to cratedAt column like this, it leads to a problem that says "ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR: Column 'createdAt' in field list is ambiguous"

```
var userId = req.body.userId;
Sensor.findAll(
{
    where : {
        userId : userId
    }, 
    attributes: [
        sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.literal('createdAt'))
    ],
    include: [{
        model: models.Temperature
    }]
}).then(function(sensor_result) {
    res.status(200).json({ status:"success", data: sensor_result });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(409).json({ status:"error", data: null, message:"Something went wrong, please try again." });
})
```

A temporary solution would be to this, but it's not efficient at all

```
Sensor.findAll(
{
    where : {
        userId : userId
    }, 
    include: [{
        model: models.Temperature,
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        limit: 1
    }]
}).then(function(sensor_result) {
    res.status(200).json({ status:"success", data: sensor_result });
}).catch(function(error) {
    res.status(409).json({ status:"error", data: null, message:"Something went wrong, please try again." });
})
```

So I would like to know if there is any option to get the MAX value of the createdAt column

Comment: Have you tried using the full column name in the second query? Based on your case it would be `sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.literal('Temperature.createdAt'))`. I think the error is caused by multiple columns having the name `createdAt` (and hence became ambiguous)

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work that way either. But anyways, I found that my logic was wrong, because that would return me the lastest time, and what I am looking for is to get the lastest Temperature inserted. So in that way the query won't work, my fault.